# File download stops in firefox, vaadin + spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, firefox, vaadin

I have a server where i would like to download a file (spring boot application with vaadin). in chrome it works perfectly fine but in firefox the download stops after ~1 min. I am able to reproduce it locally so no firewall issues. The files is downloaded through a link href

Request:

```
GET /path/to/file/test.pdf HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:8080/app/url
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/zip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2023 14:24:50 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60000
Connection: keep-alive
```

Any idea? The only thing i see is an NS_BINDING_ABORTED

Comment: Which part of the application serves the file?  Is this (dynamic)
content from inside Vaadin or a static file from Spring?

Comment: it is vaadin, a streamresource so it basically generates an anchor tag with a link to download the file

Comment: Are request- and response-headers equal in Chrome and in Firefox or is there a difference?